# It takes very long for Ubuntu 18.04 to show login screen after a reboot

Tags: gnome, 18.04, reboot, gdm

From when I reboot my Ubuntu 18.04 until I see the login screen it takes about 2 minutes. It seems that booting the kernel is not the problem. The following is the result of running `systemd-analyze time`.

```
Startup finished in 2.898s (kernel) + 10.392s (userspace) = 13.291s
graphical.target reached after 10.386s in userspace
```

My guess is that this has something to do with gdm. Here is a few lines of my `/var/log/syslog` right after a reboot.

```
Sep 23 17:27:02 desktop gnome-shell[1783]: gnome-session gave us a dead inhibitor: /org/gnome/SessionManager/Inhibitor2
Sep 23 17:27:02 desktop gnome-shell[1783]: gnome-session gave us a dead inhibitor: /org/gnome/SessionManager/Inhibitor1
Sep 23 17:27:07 desktop gsd-print-notif[1935]: Source ID 2 was not found when attempting to remove it
Sep 23 17:27:07 desktop kernel: [  534.652009] rfkill: input handler enabled
Sep 23 17:27:07 desktop systemd[1]: Stopping Authorization Manager...
Sep 23 17:27:07 desktop systemd[1]: Stopping NVIDIA Persistence Daemon...
Sep 23 17:27:07 desktop nvidia-persistenced: Received signal 15
Sep 23 17:27:07 desktop systemd[1]: Stopping Daemon for generating UUIDs...
Sep 23 17:27:07 desktop nvidia-persistenced: Socket closed.
Sep 23 17:27:07 desktop systemd[1]: Stopping RealtimeKit Scheduling Policy Service...
Sep 23 17:27:07 desktop nvidia-persistenced: PID file unlocked.
Sep 23 17:27:07 desktop systemd[1645]: Stopping D-Bus User Message Bus...
Sep 23 17:27:07 desktop nvidia-persistenced: PID file closed.
Sep 23 17:27:07 desktop systemd[1]: Stopping Daemon for power management...
Sep 23 17:27:07 desktop nvidia-persistenced: The daemon no longer has permission to remove its runtime data directory /var/run/nvidia-persistenced
Sep 23 17:27:07 desktop systemd[1]: Stopped Stop ureadahead data collection 45s after completed startup.
Sep 23 17:27:07 desktop nvidia-persistenced: Shutdown (1340)
Sep 23 17:27:07 desktop systemd[1]: Stopped target Timers.
Sep 23 17:27:07 desktop systemd[1]: Stopped Daily apt upgrade and clean activities.
Sep 23 17:27:07 desktop gsd-media-keys[1482]: g_object_notify: object class 'UpDevice' has no property named 'g-name-owner'
Sep 23 17:27:07 desktop systemd[1]: Stopping Session 3 of user sss.
Sep 23 17:27:07 desktop bluetoothd[1048]: Terminating
Sep 23 17:27:07 desktop systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 121...
Sep 23 17:27:07 desktop bluetoothd[1048]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.99 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Sep 23 17:27:07 desktop gvfsd[1789]: A connection to the bus can't be made
Sep 23 17:27:07 desktop systemd[1]: Stopped Message of the Day.
Sep 23 17:27:55 desktop systemd-modules-load[514]: Inserted module 'lp'
Sep 23 17:27:55 desktop systemd-modules-load[514]: Inserted module 'ppdev'
Sep 23 17:27:55 desktop systemd-modules-load[514]: Inserted module 'parport_pc'
Sep 23 17:27:55 desktop systemd-udevd[546]: Invalid rule /etc/udev/rules.d/50-brother-brscan4-libsane-type1.rules:9: unknown key 'SYSFS{idVendor}'
Sep 23 17:27:55 desktop systemd-udevd[546]: Invalid rule /etc/udev/rules.d/50-brother-libsane-type1-inst.rules:14: unknown key 'SYSFS{idVendor}'
Sep 23 17:27:55 desktop systemd[1]: Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...
Sep 23 17:27:55 desktop systemd[1]: Started Set the console keyboard layout.
Sep 23 17:27:55 desktop systemd[1]: Reached target Local File Systems (Pre).
Sep 23 17:27:55 desktop systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for gtk-common-themes, revision 319...
Sep 23 17:27:55 desktop systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for gnome-system-monitor, revision 57...
Sep 23 17:27:55 desktop kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 4.15.0-34-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-047) (gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)) #37-Ubuntu SMP Mon Aug 27 15:21:48 UTC 2018 (Ubuntu 4.15.0-34.37-generic 4.15.18)
Sep 23 17:27:55 desktop systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for gnome-characters, revision 103...
```

The most obvious delay here is before It prints `Inserted module 'lp'` which is about 50 sec. I'd appreciate if someone could help me with this.